# CSS: How to have grid respect margins when accounting for gap space?

Tags: css, css-grid

[image]

I have a basic grid where the 2 columns should be taking up 50% each but it looks like the gap is throwing this off.  How would I account for that and maintain body margins?

```
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
        grid-template-rows: 200px 200px;
        grid-gap: 20px;
        margin: 40px;

    }
    .grid-item {
        background-color: red;
        justify-content: center;

    }
    .g1 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
    }

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item g1">
    foo
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the columns, try doing box-sizing: border-box; and remove the grid-gap property. The box-sizing makes the CSS take into account padding and borders.